# MVC Rss agreggator caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rss

I am building an RSS agreggator and displaying last entry from feed to the users browsing and around 20 feeds per page. I can see that it would be a pain to pull last item from each of 20 feeds each time any user loads page. So I was thinking that the best way would be to cache feeds for one day.

Is the cache stored in memory or on disk? I am worried that caching so many items could reach memory limit on my host and stop pool.

How is this type of chaching done in MVC? I know it goes something like `Page.Cache.Insert` in WebForms. Im using `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` to get last entry from feed.

I have a custom model class that holds Feed Title, Feed Adress , Item title , Item Adress and First 200 letters of content so that should not consume a lot of memory.

Can anybody explain to me  where is cache stored, and can it hurt my app when chaching for a period as long as one day? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to define an action in the controller as cached ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx)):

```
 [OutputCache(Duration=10, VaryByParam="none")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

The datas are saved in the memory. You can manage the outputcache in the [IIS Configurations](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/caching)

There are already defeault limitation attributes:

**Maximum cached response size** (in bytes) Specifies the maximum size of a cached response for both the user-mode and kernel-mode caches. The default value is 262144 bytes. This field is enabled at the server level only; it is read-only at all other levels.

**Cache size limit** (in MB) Configures the size limit of both the user-mode and kernel-mode caches. You can type a size (in MB) or type 0. If you type 0, IIS uses half of the available physical memory or virtual memory, whichever is less. This field is enabled at the server level only; it is read-only at all other levels.

Comment: Well the problem is I don't need whole action being cached since oder of display of feeds changes all the time (but the content remains the same)